FileNotFound error to Python Image with PIL
I have an assignment, and I am creating a program that lists some options and displays images depending on what you choose. What I'm struggling on is that some of my images work, but some don't. I'm using pillow for my image library.
This is my code:
def display_f(): # Display female avatar
    img = Image.open("C:/Users/name/OneDrive/Pictures/CSP - project/r_f.png")
    img.show()

The error I get:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\CSP-project\\r_f.png'

I copy-pasted the exact path, so I don't know why I'm getting this error. What am I doing wrong?

I believe your problem is caused by the spaces on the path "CSP - poject", if you check the error it try to find a directory without space

It seems you are using an incorrect path in your function. Try to use forward slashes in the path as  I hope this might fix this. If the issue persists try using raw string like this:-
img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Pictures\CSP - project\r_f.png")

It's simple - there is no such file. What's interesting is that the path you're supposedly giving to Image.open() is not the same as the reported filename. I doubt very much if the code you've shown is generating that exception
